# returning to a previous page does not give correct checkbox value

Tags: php, jquery

After submitting a search query to a php file I try to go back to the previous page in order to test if all is well e.g.

```
> search.php [goto] > results.php [backto] > search.php
```

I have this bit of JQuery code which checks if a checkbox is checked upon landing on the search.php file

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
   if($("input[name=filterSite]").not(':checked')){
       alert("not checked");
   }
});
```

It always returns `not checked` even though the html markup is always set to the following

```
<input name="filterSite" type="checkbox"   id="filterSite" checked="checked" />
```

What could be causing this problem? and how do I fix it?

Comment: How are you going back to `results.php`? Is there a submit button, or are you using the browser's back button?

Comment: jquery is checkinf for filterSite, and input name is filterSize. Maybe thats why?

Comment: i am going back using the browser "back" button in chrome

Comment: @Tom sorry about that, wrong input, it should have been "filterSite"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most jQuery methods return objects, not boolean values (so that you can chain methods to get to the desired result). The return value of .not() will always be an object (which will evaluate to true in the above condition).

What you want is one of these two:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
   if($("input[name=filterSite]").not(':checked').size()){
       alert("not checked");
   }
});
```

OR:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
   if($("input[name=filterSite]").is(':checked') == false){
       alert("not checked");
   }
});
```

.size() will return the number of elements which are currently part of the selector

.is() returns boolean, evaluating whether or not the elements in the selector match the given condition

Answer (score 0):

your jquery should be

```
 $(document).ready(function(){         
 if(!$("input[name=filterSite]:checked")){
       alert("not checked");
   }
});​
```